# Node.js Bluebird Promise complains of "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

For making a outgoing api call, I am using restler wrapped in a bluebird promise object. However, I am getting a `Possibly unhandled TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` at `node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js`.

This happens even without JSON.stringify. It is happening at the level of promise.js.

What can I do about this?

```
                rest.postJson(uri, body).then(
                    function(response) {
                        console.log(response.access.token.id);
                        console.log(response.statusCode);
                        res.send(response.access.token.id);
                    }, function(error) {
                        console.log(error.statusCode);
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
                           //res.send(error);
                        }); 




Possibly unhandled TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:205:19)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:121:21)
    at /home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/app/scripts/proxy/proxies_express_module.js:39:29
    at tryCatch1 (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:43:21)
    at Promise$_callHandler [as _callHandler] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:627:13)
    at Promise$_settlePromiseFromHandler [as _settlePromiseFromHandler] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:641:18)
    at Promise$_settlePromiseAt [as _settlePromiseAt] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:804:14)
    at Promise$_settlePromises [as _settlePromises] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:938:14)
    at Promise$_rejectPromises [as _rejectPromises] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:931:10)
```

**UPDATE**: Here are the keys of the error object if it helps any:

```
[ '_readableState',
  'readable',
  'domain',
  '_events',
  '_maxListeners',
  'socket',
  'connection',
  'httpVersion',
  'complete',
  'headers',
  'trailers',
  '_pendings',
  '_pendingIndex',
  'url',
  'method',
  'statusCode',
  'client',
  '_consuming',
  '_dumped',
  'httpVersionMajor',
  'httpVersionMinor',
  'upgrade',
  'req',
  'pipe',
  'addListener',
  'on',
  'pause',
  'resume',
  'read',
  'rawEncoded',
  'raw' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

No. When you don't pass a string to [express' `res.send`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) but an object (like `error`), it will call `JSON.stringify` internally. This will for sure not happen in `promise.js` (however, Bluebird does weird things to the stacktrace). Try

```
res.send(error.message);
```

Comment: I tried `console.log(error.message);` and it shows as undefined. But isn't the error happening at `at Promise$_rejectPromises [as _rejectPromises] (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:931:10)`?

Comment: That's where the *call* to your promise callback might originate, but the error is *thrown* `at Object.stringify (native)`, called by `ServerResponse.res.json (/home/one/try/cloudimageshare-monitoring/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:205:19)`, called by…

Comment: Well, I guess the problem is the api is returning a json that a nested json. How do I get this response back the client from express.js?

Comment: It looks like your api is throwing an error that is not an `Error`. Does `console.log(error)` tell you more about it?

Comment: The API is returning a 401 because I made my auth incorrect on purpose to trigger the error. Other than that, error is a huge object.

Comment: Huge object, yes, but what type of object? You might need to show us your `rest.postJson(uri, body)` code if you want to get help with fixing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57117/discussion-between-dman-and-bergi).